# scrapy form-filling when form posts to a second web page

Tags: python, scrapy

New to scrapy and wondering if anyone can point me to a sample project using scrapy to submit to HTML forms that have hidden fields in cases where the action page of the form is not the same address as where the form itself is presented.

What is the easiest way to do this in Scrapy? I can see that you could write two spiders - one first to get the html with the form and pick out all the hidden fields and then a second one to use the info with the hidden fields to submit the form.

I am wondering if there is a 1-step process for this instead (the Scrapy request documentation seems to assume it's all on the same page when it says using FormRequest.from_response will take care of hidden fields). If so, can someone tell me where I can find the steps of the 1 step process?

Comment: what have you done so far? update your question with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormRequest`extends the `Request`object. So you can get the `formdata` inclusive the hidden values with `FormRequest.from_response` and, if needed, change the `url` after that.

Demo Pseudo Code:

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/FormPage.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        request = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            callback=self.parse_response_from_Form
        )
        request.replace(url='http://www.other-site.com/')
        return request

    def parse_response_from_Form(self, response):
        # go on here...
        pass
```